# 4 Checkbox group to filter a repeater

Tags: velo

I want to create a recipe page with 3 different checkbox groups for different filters.

Currently, I have 1 checkbox group and linked it to a repeater.

Could anyone assist in guiding me on how to add 2 more checkbox groups to the repeater?

I went digging online but have yet to find a solution

```js
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const databaseName = 'Recipes1';
const databaseField = 'tags';

$w.onReady(function() {
  $w('#checkboxGroup1').onChange((event) => {
    const selectedBox = $w('#checkboxGroup1').value;
    addItemstoRepeater(selectedBox);
  })
});


function addItemstoRepeater(selectedOption = []) {
  let dataQuery = wixData.query(databaseName);

  if (selectedOption.length > 0) {
    dataQuery = dataQuery.hasSome(databaseField, selectedOption);
  }

  dataQuery
    .find()
    .then(results => {
      const filtereditemsReady = results.items;
      $w('#repeater1').data = filtereditemsReady;
    })
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by groups? A repeater renders **items**, not groups. Unfortunately, there is no "repeater of repeaters". You can add more repeaters by hand, one for each possible group.

Comment: Oh my apologies. What i meant was i wish to create 2 more checkbox to filter the repeater table. Example, the user can filter the table by cuisine (checkbox1), dish type (checkbox2) and ingredients (checkbox 3). 

After that, the table will display the reults based on the user selection

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is a data query to fetch the items according to user selection.

In order to build a filter you need to use a [dataset](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-dataset/introduction), [connect the dataset to your repeater](https://support.wix.com/en/article/displaying-collection-content-in-a-repeater) or table. View a [filter example here](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/custom-store-filters), it shows you how to filter a dataset using multiple selections.

From my perspective, filter function for 3 checkbox groups should be like below

```
let checkbox1;
let checkbox2;
let checkbox3;

const filter = (ck1, ck2, ck3) => { 

    if(checkbox1 !== ck1 || checkbox2 !== ck2 || checkbox3 !== ck3) {
        let newFilter = wixData.filter();

        if(ck1)
        newFilter = newFilter.hasSome('fieldKey1', ck1);
        
        if(ck2)
        newFilter = newFilter.hasSome('fieldKey2', ck2);
        
        if(ck3)
        newFilter = newFilter.hasSome('fieldKey3', ck3);
        
        $w("#datasetId").setFilter(newFilter);
        
        setVariables(ck1, ck2, ck3);
    }
}

const setVariables = (ck1, ck2, ck3) => {
    checkbox1 = ck1;
    checkbox2 = ck2;
    checkbox3 = ck3;
}
```

You will need to study the example to adapt to code according to your needs.